# Why do Meta and Stack Overflow requires separate authentication

Tags: discussion, login, authentication

Why do Meta and Stack Overflow require separate authentication? Why auth details are not shared between all the Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: probably issues with separate domains...

Comment: Your first question is slightly different than the 2nd... normally meta sites share the same authentication as the main site, but Meta Stack Overflow is special since it serves as Meta.StackExchange.com (meta for the Stack Exchange engine) in addition to the meta site for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Think of Stack Exchange as a building with many rooms, each site is a room. One can just view each room from the outside, or enter the room using identification card. The OpenID is this card, and has to be used in each site separately.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, it's all useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why auth details are not shared between all the Stack products?

Because we don't deal with authentication. We use openId for that.